# Cant add formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add a formula in VBA and I have tried every variation of "" and it still doesn't work. I am trying to add in a cell that has just been added as part of the process (so I still need to use the offset).

```
allocatedtoSpend.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 4).Formula = "=IF('Expected Project Summary'!$I$20<0, """"Warning - you have exceeded the total budget"""",IF(VLOOKUP("" & allocatedtoSpend.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 0).Value & "",'Expected Project Summary'!$A$7:$I$16,7,FALSE)<0, """"Warning - you have exceeded the line budget"""", ""))"
```

Answer (score 3):

I used an "Help String" to help me debug it, so the code I got is below.

(I prefer using `Chr(34)` to get the `"` sign)

```
Dim str As String

str = "=IF('Expected Project Summary'!$I$20<0, " & Chr(34) & "Warning - you have exceeded the total budget" & Chr(34) & ",IF(VLOOKUP(" & allocatedtoSpend.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 0).Value & ",'Expected Project Summary'!$A$7:$I$16,7,FALSE)<0, " & Chr(34) & "Warning - you have exceeded the line budget" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))"   
Debug.Print str

allocatedtoSpend.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 4).Formula = str
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula string should be:

```
"=IF('Expected Project Summary'!$I$20<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the total budget"",IF(VLOOKUP(""" & allocatedtospend.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 0).Value & """,'Expected Project Summary'!$A$7:$I$16,7,FALSE)<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the line budget"", """"))"
```

assuming your lookup value is text. If it is numeric, you would need:

```
"=IF('Expected Project Summary'!$I$20<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the total budget"",IF(VLOOKUP(" & allocatedtospend.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 0).Value & ",'Expected Project Summary'!$A$7:$I$16,7,FALSE)<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the line budget"", """"))"
```

It's probably easier to simply include a cell address, then it will work for either:

```
"=IF('Expected Project Summary'!$I$20<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the total budget"",IF(VLOOKUP(" & allocatedtospend.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-8, 0).Address & ",'Expected Project Summary'!$A$7:$I$16,7,FALSE)<0, ""Warning - you have exceeded the line budget"", """"))"
```